# How to hide programmatically the navigation bar on iOS Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome, html5-fullscreen

I'm looking for a way to dismiss the navigation bar of the iOS Chrome browser, programmatically. I mean, without the use of user gestures.

I've tried the Web Fullscreen API without success.

It looks like this Browser has poor documentation and resources.

Comment: Why do you think that this is possible?

Comment: Hi, it's what I'm trying to know... is it possible or not? I need this in a project... @Azat

Comment: Chrome hides that bar only when you are scrolling content, it seems like you cannot write any code to do it from your page